# Como puedo poner el checkbox a la misma altura que un label?

Tags: html, css

Hace un tiempito vengo batallando con esto, quiero que el checkbox de recibir novedades este a la misma altura que su label y que sea un poco mas grande.

```css
.input-group {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 33px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.input--style-2 {
    padding: 9px 0;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
           <form>
           <div class="input-group">
        <label contenteditable="false" for="checkbox" style="width: auto;" class="input--style-2" type="text" name="res_code">Deseo recibir novedades</label>
                <input  style="width:auto" class="input--style-2 checkbox" type="checkbox" checked name="acepta"/>                          
            </div>   
</form>
```

En el snippet se me ve bien pero en la vista real no, que estoy haciendo mal?

Si es necesario algo mas, haganmelo saber

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le quito el style:"width: auto" al checkbox, aparece asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probé tu código, te invito a probarlo suelto en un html aparte y funciona tal cual lo necesitás. Seguro no hay algo mas en el CSS que te modifique valores de estilo para el label o el checkbox que no estemos viendo?

Comment: Lo copie tal cual lo tengo en el codigo, no le eh quitado ni agregado nada al momento de realizar esta pregunta

Comment: En el snippet funciona bien, y si creas un html sin enlazar a otro css también funciona bien. Eso significa que esa parte del código está correcta. El inconveniente debe estar en otro parámetro del CSS que afecte al label en puntual o a todos los labels.

Comment: No se si en tu proyecto estés utilizando boostrap, de ser así podría ser que input-group este chocando con algún elemento de la class de boostrap. Quizas añadiendo una letra o un número más te resulte diferente input-group1

Comment: Incluso tienes una clase llamada `checkbox` que no vemos en el código que proporcionas. No habrá algún parámetro de estilo afectando esa clase?

Comment: la clase checkbox no esta siendo utilizada, deberia sacarla para que no haya confusion, debe ser un problema del boostrap, ya comente todo el css y es como si lo tuviese de decoracion

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en la vista _Layout.cshtml, estaba usando esto `<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`.

Al quitarlo el checkbox se puso en la posicion deseada sin cambiar nada en otro lado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que era lo que te comentaba es muy probable que en esa librería dentro de sus class tenga un elemento llamado igual al que tu estas indicando, y al momento que lo encuentra choca y no respeta ni el de boostrap ni tu css.  Por eso te comentaba que a lo mejor añadiendo una letra o numero al nombre de tu css podría significar un cambio.  Saludos

Comment: Es correcto Cesarin, opté por sacarlo de la solución ya que no lo necesitaba, el resto de css está siendo usado perfectamente, Gracias a todos por su atención!